# How to convert all thymeleaf input fields toUpperCase?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

```
<input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           th:value="${dto.field}" name="field" />
```

Is it possible to directly convert the input values to upper case?
Like pseudocode:

```
th:value="${#StringUtils.toUpperCase(dto.field)}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access methods from the [StringUtils](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.1.6.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/util/StringUtils.html) class using the `#strings` utility object.

In your case:

```
th:value="${#strings.toUpperCase(dto.field)}"
```

Comment: @membersound no problem. Sorry if that sounded demanding. Didn't mean it to but reading it back I didn't phrase myself well. Anyway, thanks!